# Can I calculate the probality of a test being true $Pr(T)$ from $Pr(T|V)+ Pr(T|not V)$ if I know that Pr(V)+Pr(not V)=1?

Tags: probability

If have $T$="The virus test is positive." and $V$="There really is a virus."
and I know that $Pr(V)+Pr(\bar{V})=1$, can I then say that

$Pr(T)=Pr(T|V)+Pr(T|\bar{V})$

and how do I show that formally, based on calculation rules?

Comment: It would be $\Pr(T)=\Pr(T\mid V)\Pr(V)+\Pr(T\mid V')\Pr(V')$.  Here I am using $V'$ for not $V$.

Comment: You cannot say that. $~$ You *can* say $\Pr(T)  = \Pr(T\mid V)\Pr(V)+\Pr(T\mid\bar V)\Pr(\bar V)$ by the**Law of Total Probability**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\Pr(T) & = \Pr\big(T\cap(V\cup \neg V)\big) & \textsf{by Law of Complements}
\\ & =\Pr\big((T\cap V)\cup(T\cap\neg V)\big) & \textsf{by Distribution}
\\ & =\Pr(T\cap V)+\Pr(T\cap\neg V) &  \textsf{because the Events are Disjoint}
\\ & =\Pr(T\mid V)\Pr(V)+\Pr(T\mid\neg V)\Pr(\neg V) & \textsf{by Conditional Probability def}^n
\end{align}$$

That is all.